# How to View Number of OpenGL Draw Calls In XCode

Tags: xcode, opengl-es

In XCode, I can click "Analyze" in the Debug Navigator to capture an OpenGL frame.  It will show me the total number of OpenGL calls.  However, I am interested in only the number of draw calls.  Is there any way to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you interested in examining only draw calls in the sequence of captured OpenGL ES commands, or in a statistic that counts only draw calls?

For the former, click the flag button at the lower left of the navigator after capturing a frame:

[image]

For the latter, switch one of the variables views (in the debug area at the bottom of the Xcode window) to show the Auto view, and look in the Frame Statistics section:

[image]

For more on the Xcode OpenGL ES frame debugger, check out [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/ToolsOverview/ToolsOverview.html).